# Globally using UNIX line endings in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, newline

I wanted to know if any of you guys knew a tip to globally (or maybe on a project-by-project basis ?) use Unix line breaks in all of my project files.

I'm aware of the "Advanced Save Options..." menu entry but first it's a file-by-file option and second it does not seem to really work (for example if I select Unix endings and change the file the day after, it's gonna insert windows line endings in the middle of the Unix endings...). The advanced save popup mentions a "Current Setting" which is the default choice, so I was wondering if there was an option somewhere this was referring to ?

If the stock VS can't properly do this, are you maybe aware of a plugin that does the job ?

Thanks !

**Edit** : After trying a global plugin (see Sir.Tiddlesworth's answer), I don't think it's a viable solution. So a project-by-project suggestion would be welcome !

Comment: Did you ever find a satisfiable solution?

Comment: Nope, sorry. What I ended up doing is using another editor for the projects that needed special care (Visual Studio Code actually, which surprisingly has a much easier time dealing with multiple line ending types)

Comment: Thanks for getting back on that, I'll check it out sometime. Meanwhile I wrote a small programme to be run on some event (like Build) that converts all code files to my preferred line endings. Really annoying hack though.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a few months old, but I will leave an answer here just in case.

There is a pretty good plugin for Visual Studio 2013 (and below) called Strip'em. It is really easy to use, and it converts the lines endings as you save the file.

http://www.grebulon.com/software/stripem.php

Comment: For the record: I did try this plugin, but because it sets the line endings globally (all files, all projects), I feel it is an acceptable solution only if you exclusively open linux files in Visual Studio. Having both Windows and Linux projects, I always forgot to swith on/off the plugin depending on the project type, so that solution isn't for me unfortunately.